# user_id not in auth_user table after changing UserModel

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-migration

I have had normal custom user model. I have many users also in database and other models pointing to this user model. Now i changed the user model so that it inherits from django's user model.

I did this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(User):
 #custom fields...
 ...
```

and tried to migrate. but it is giving me error saying `(user_id)=(9)` not in auth_user table. this is because other models are now pointing to auth_user and auth_user is now new and doesnot contain user with id 9.

I have many data in db, now i am really stuck. what to do?

Comment: First of all, i recommend using a different name `class UserProfile(User):`

Comment: @karthikr, now that error message is gone, but now i have new one: the user id is not in auth_user table. i know why this happens but i dont know how to solve it. can you pls help me?

Comment: can you edit the question with the error (stack trace) ?

Comment: In my opinion, the cleanest way is to have a `OneToOne` relationship between UserProfile and User objects. That way you can handle the migrations gracefully too. Another advantage would be It would need lot fewer code changes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34552/discussion-between-doniyor-and-karthikr)